# How does stdin work with the following commands

Tags: bash, stdin

I am struggling to understand how does stdin work with these 3 commands:

1. `$ echo < file1.txt`
2. `$ ls < file1.txt > file2.txt`
3. `$ pwd < file1.txt > file2.txt`

The contents of the file `file1.txt` are "Hello World"

As far as I understand, `stdin` can be an input from your keyboard, but also contents of files can be used instead of your keyboard. For example, both commands `cat file1.txt` and `cat < file1.txt`  output the same: `Hello World`.

1. Using this logic, commands `echo Hello World` and `echo < file1.txt` should output the same? Surprisingly for me, no. The first command outputs `Hello World`, whereas the second command outputs nothing. *Why?*

2, 3) I don't have an idea what these commands do. It looks like they just ignore the `< file1.txt` part and just do the `ls > file2.txt` part. *Why?*

Comment: All of those commands do not attempt to read from stdin because they were never designed to read from stdin. They don't have features that require reading from stdin.

Comment: Don't use logic, use the man page, e.g. [man 1 bash](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html) If you did want to misuse redirection to get output with `echo` you could use the bashism of redirection within a command substitution, e.g. `echo $(<file1.txt)`. Note, you are providing an argument to `echo`, it's not reading `stdin`. Same would apply to `ls`. `pwd` takes no arguments. (which [man 1 pwd](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pwd.1.html) would confirm)

Comment: The `<` open the files for reading while the `>` opens the file for writing, Redirection happens before anything else from the shell.

Comment: See `LESS='+/^REDIRECTION' man bash` or the online [REDIRECTION](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html) section of the bash manual